# Decrypt data in typescript that have been encrypted in python

Tags: python, typescript, encryption

I am trying to decrypt data that has been previously encrypted in python, but I can not.

I encrypt the data using the following in python:

```
iv = Random.new().read( AES.block_size )
cipher = AES.new(secret_key,AES.MODE_CBC, iv) 
encrypdata = base64.b64encode(iv + cipher.encrypt(data))
```

I decrypt it with the following in python:

```
enc = base64.b64decode(encrypdata)
iv = enc[:16]
cipher = AES.new(secret_key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv )
decryptdata = cipher.decrypt( enc[16:] ).strip()
```

But when I try it with typescript it fails:

```
enc = Buffer.from(encrypdata, 'base64').toString();
iv = enc.toString().slice(0,16);
cipher = crypto.createDecipheriv("aes-256-cbc",secret_key,  iv );
decryptdata = cipher.update( enc.slice(16) ).strip();
```

The current error that I am receiving is "Invalid IV length", but the length of iv is 16.

Can someone tell me how to accomplish this?
Thanks.

Comment: I don't know anything about typescript, but that `toString()` call looks bad... encrypted data is a byte sequence, not a string.

Comment: Yes, why not just `iv = enc.slice(0,16);`?

Comment: I remove toString and it dosnt work. 
I think the whole decrypt part fails, not just the iv part, but I do not know how to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the following configuration I was able to decrypt the data:

```
     enc = Buffer.from(datos, 'base64');
     iv = enc.slice(0, 16);
     crypt = enc.toString('base64', 16);
     decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-128-cbc', secret_key, iv);
     decipher.setAutoPadding(false);
     dec = decipher.update(crypt,'base64','utf-8');
     dec += decipher.final('utf-8');
```